# InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 582: Unexpected data found

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

when i fetch data i get this error **InvalidArgumentException in Carbon.php line 582: Unexpected data found.**

```
 public function index()
{
    $bars = Question::all();
     return  $bars ;
}
```

Comment: how does your Qeustion model look like? do you use Carbon there?

Comment: could you please add the full error message

Comment: In your question show that code which related error.

Answer (score 0):

By default when fetching with Eloquent Model, the time stamp fields (created_at, updated_at, deleted_at and other date ) should be in `mysql date time format`, because Eloquent will convert that fields into Carbon Object. else while retrieving if it is not in correct format the above error which you've mentioned arises,

to overcome this make the timestamp propery false in your Question Model

```
public $timestamps = false;
```